# async library spawning multiple node processes

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm using the async library to traverse an array and perform db operations on each element of the array. I'm using the `forEachLimit` function.

When the execution starts, I see multiple instances of node. I'm using htop to monitor the processes. I say many instance, because each has a unique pid.

Is this expected?

Comment: `async` itself doesn't spawn processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not seeing threads? Node uses a thread-pool for some operations. Press "t" to see the tree view of `htop`, or use "H" to hide threads.

If you're seeing multiple processes then you must be spawning them inside of your functions that are run with async. You haven't said anything about your code so it's hard to tell you anything more than that.

Comment: The function makes a db call (with sequelize as the ORM) and then an https request. I doubt any of these spawn a process.

Comment: htop, by default, shows threads (which, at least on Linux, have their own PID) as if they were processes (they differ in the color). When you open the tree view (`t`), you see this more clearly.

Comment: @devxeq I doubt it too but to dispel our doubts you would have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See the first sentence in my question, though: Are you sure you're not seeing threads? Node uses a thread-pool for some operations.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, that's why I asked if the OP is sure that those are processes and not threads.

Comment: @rsp yes, and that's why I upvoted your answer :) I just added my comment as a bit of background.

Comment: @robertklep Oh, I see. :) I'll add a hint about tree view to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. htop was showing threads, but the different pids threw me off. Thanks. :)